# Implementing merge sort in java

Tags: java, mergesort

Here's my implementation of Merge Sort in java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort
{
  private static int [] LeftSubArray(int [] Array)
  {
    int [] leftHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(Array, 0, Array.length / 2);
    return leftHalf;
  }

  private static int [] RightSubArray(int [] Array)
  {
    int [] rightHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(Array, Array.length / 2 + 1, Array.length);
    return rightHalf;
  }

  private static int [] Sort(int [] A)
  {
    if(A.length > 1)
    {
      return Merge( Sort( LeftSubArray(A) ) , Sort( RightSubArray(A) ) );
    }
    else
    {
      return A;
    }
  }

  private static int [] Merge(int [] B, int [] C)
  {
    int [] D = new int[B.length + C.length];
    int i,j,k;
    i = j = k = 0;
    while(k < D.length)
    {
      if(i == B.length)
      {
        //Copy the remainder of C into D
        while(k < D.length){ D[k++] = C[j++]; }
      }
      if(j == C.length)
      {
        //Copy the remainder of B into D
        while(k < D.length){ D[k++] = B[i++]; }
      }
      if(i<B.length && j<C.length)
      {
        if(B[i] > C[j]){ D[k++] = B[i++]; }
        else { D[k++] = C[j++]; }
      }
    }
    return D;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int [] array = {1,3,5,2,4};
    int [] sorted = MergeSort.Sort(array);
    for(int i = 0;i < sorted.length; ++i)
    {
      System.out.print(sorted[i] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

The output I get is

```
2 1
```

From what I can tell there seems a problem with my division of the right sub array.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not really helpful, but you should use lower case variable, parameter and method names. It is the accepted java coding standard, and makes the code easier to read for others. Also it is good practice to use meaningful variable names (e.g. instead of b and c, leftArray and rightArray would make the code more readable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the javadoc of copyOfRange:

```
Parameters:
original - the array from which a range is to be copied
from - the initial index of the range to be copied, **inclusive**
to - the final index of the range to be copied, **exclusive**. (This index may lie outside the array.)
```

I highlighted two words you should pay special attention to ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If your array has 10 elements, then LeftSubArray copies elements 0..5, and RightSubArray copies elements 6..10.  But if the first element is at index 0, then there is no element w/ an index 10.  And if copyOfRange(a,b) gives elements indexed a..b-1, then LeftSA is yielding 0..4 and RightSA is yielding 6..9.  Either way, your assumption about division seems to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

With your code [1,3,5,2,4] is split into [1,3] and [2,4]. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code works: you had couple of errors:
see next diffs:

- rightSubArray method
- copy the remainder of B
- copy the remainder of C

The code that works follows:

```
public class MergeSort
{
  private static int [] LeftSubArray(int [] Array)
  {
    int [] leftHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(Array, 0, Array.length / 2);
    return leftHalf;
  }

  private static int [] RightSubArray(int [] Array)
 {
    int[] rightHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(Array, Array.length / 2,
            Array.length);
 return rightHalf;
 }

 private static int [] Sort(int [] A)
 {
  if(A.length > 1)
  {
    return Merge( Sort( LeftSubArray(A) ) , Sort( RightSubArray(A) ) );
  }
  else
{
  return A;
}
}

private static int [] Merge(int [] B, int [] C)
{
  int [] D = new int[B.length + C.length];
  int i,j,k;
  i = j = k = 0;
  while(k < D.length)
  {
    if(i == B.length)
    {
    //Copy the remainder of C into D
            while (j < C.length) {
                D[k++] = C[j++];
            }
  }
  if(j == C.length)
  {
    //Copy the remainder of B into D
            while (i < B.length) {
                D[k++] = B[i++];
            }
  }
        if (i < B.length && j < C.length)
  {
            if (B[i] > C[j]) {
                D[k++] = B[i++];
            } else {
                D[k++] = C[j++];
            }
  }
}
return D;
}

 public static void main(String [] args)
  {
   int [] array = {1,3,5,2,4};
   int [] sorted = MergeSort.Sort(array);
   for(int i = 0;i < sorted.length; ++i)
   {
     System.out.print(sorted[i] + " ");
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a rigth solution in Robert Sedgewick book "Algorithms on java language"

1. Read [here about merge](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/)